# How do you go to school or How do you get to school?

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

Which is correct between How do you get to __ vs How do you go to ___? Can you also explain why it's the correct way to ask this question or how do they differ?

Comment: You could use _get_ or _travel. Go_ sounds a bit odd to me, because _go to school_ often means _attend school_; but in some contexts it might be used for asking about the mode of transport.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell what meaning you're trying to convey. Neither one is wrong, but they emphasize different things. To pick a different example (to eliminate the confusion with "attend school"): "... get to the store" vs "... go to the store": *get to* emphasizes arriving at the destination; *go to* emphasizes the process. I might "go to the store [in a hurry], or [while hungry]." But I "get to the store [by car, bus, or subway]."

Answer (score 2):

Both:

> "**How do you go to school?"** and 
> "**How do you get to school?"**

are grammatically acceptable.

The Cambridge dictionary has [a page about "get vs go", including warnings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/get-or-go) and arguments can be made for why each sentence is preferred by some over the other, but both sentences are used commonly where I live (I was born and raised in Ontario, Canada and did my PhD in Oxford, England).